# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient

Tags: azure-devops, entity-framework-core, nuget, .net-standard, .net-4.7.2

I am calling a .net standard 2.0 library from a framework 4.7.2 test project sucessfully.
[image: references]

If I take my .net standard 2.0 dll (SBD.Standard) and create a new winforms project that references it then I get asked to add

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, 
then Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer, 
then Microsoft.Data.SqlClient
```

and then my project runs successfully. (Although it would be ideal if the extra packages were added automatically)

[image]

However trouble occurs if I try to distribute my library via a Nuget Package built using Azure DevOps.

However when I distribute the standard library via Nuget ( Using Azure DevOps to create the Nuget ) and include it in a new project I have an error.

The call stack is

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=1.0.19269.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=23ec7fc2d6eaa4a5' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerConnection.CreateDbConnection()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.get_DbConnection()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.CreateCommand(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, Guid commandId, DbCommandMethod commandMethod)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.InitializeReader(DbContext _, Boolean result)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at SBD.Standard.Helpers.HandyFuncs.QueueCommand(ApiDbContext connect, WorkTypeEnum workType, String
```

The line of code that is causing the issue is

```
public static int QueueCommand(ApiDbContext connect, WorkTypeEnum workType, string description, int jobId, int signature, XElement elem)
{
    var command =
        connect.EngineCommandQueues.SingleOrDefault(
            c =>
                (c.Status == 0|| c.Status == 2) &&
                c.Signature == signature);
```

I did find that I needed to install the following packages

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.1
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 3.1.1 which has a dependency on Microsoft.Data.SqlClient >=1.019269.1
```

I see that Microsoft.Data.SQLClient v1.0.19269.1 is intalled

I tried installing System.Linq

I see the note in Nuget for Microsoft.Data.SqlClient

> When running on Windows, this library has a dependency on
>   Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI on .NET Framework

and have Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI v1.0.19235.1 installed

I tried upgrading Microsoft.Data.SqlClient to 1.1 and the error changed to

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNILoadHandle' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNINativeMethodWrapper' threw an exception. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Failed to load C:\Dev2\Combridge\SBD.ComBridge\UnitTestProjectStandard\bin\Debug\x86\SNI.dll ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The specified module could not be found
    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNINativeMethodWrapper..cctor() in E:\agent1\_work\31\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\Interop\SNINativeMethodWrapper.cs:line 64
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNINativeMethodWrapper.SNIInitialize()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNILoadHandle..ctor() in E:\agent1\_work\31\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\TdsParserSafeHandles.cs:line 36
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNILoadHandle..cctor() in E:\agent1\_work\31\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\TdsParserSafeHandles.cs:line 17
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser..cctor() in E:\agent1\_work\31\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\TdsParser.cs:line 166
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) in E:\agent1\_work\31\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\ProviderBase\DbConnectionPool.cs:line 1411
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) in E:\agent1\_work\31\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\ProviderBase\DbConnectionPool.cs:line 1310
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) in E:\agent1\_work\31\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\ProviderBase\DbConnectionFactory.cs:line 357
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) in E:\agent1\_work\31\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\ProviderBase\DbConnectionInternal.cs:line 773
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) in E:\agent1\_work\31\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\ProviderBase\DbConnectionClosed.cs:line 72
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) in E:\agent1\_work\31\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlConnection.cs:line 1860
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) in E:\agent1\_work\31\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlConnection.cs:line 1853
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() in E:\agent1\_work\31\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlConnection.cs:line 1421
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.InitializeReader(DbContext _, Boolean result)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext )
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
```

[Update]
Reading [This GitHub post](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/211) it seems it could have something to do with Azure Devops

The post mentions

> Win32Exception: Failed to load
>   C:__source_code\repo1\Simplified\bin\x86\SNI.dll So it's trying to
>   load the 32 bit version of sni.dll and it isn't present.
>
> That makes me suspect that you build it on a 64 bit system and then
>   just transferred the files to the other machine. You need to publish
>   the project for an x86 target to get the right native dependency
>   resolved. Give it a try.

I am running Windows 10 so I dont see why it would be trying to load a 32 bit version of sni.dll

I can see in the Azure Artifiacts

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI 1.0.19235.1

[Update]

I see from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43995432/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-abstrac) that I need to force MSBuild to create / update a YourProject.dll.config file containing the necessary binding redirects.
So Nuget should be creating that config file too. I wonder how that effects things.

My azure-pipelines.yml is

```
# .NET Desktop
# Build and run tests for .NET Desktop or Windows classic desktop solutions.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/windows/dot-net

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  Major: '2'
  Minor: '0'
  Patch: '0'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '>=4.3.0'
    checkLatest: true

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: pack
    packagesToPack: '**/*.csproj'
    versioningScheme: byPrereleaseNumber
    majorVersion: '$(Major)'
    minorVersion: '$(Minor)'
    patchVersion: '$(Patch)'

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: pack
    packagesToPack: '**/*.vbproj'
    versioningScheme: byPrereleaseNumber
    majorVersion: '$(Major)'
    minorVersion: '$(Minor)'
    patchVersion: '$(Patch)'

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet push'
  inputs:
    command: push
    publishVstsFeed: 'SBDCommonFeed'
    allowPackageConflicts: true
```

[Update]

I tried changing the yaml to use dotnet pack but get an error

[image: error]

[Update]

I tried replacing the pack section of the yaml with

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'pack'
    selectOrConfig: 'config'
    nugetConfigPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/NuGet.config'
    externalEndpoints: $(externalFeedCredential)
```

Now I get [image: resource authorization issue] Resource Authorization Issue

When I click the button to authorize I get a message: insufficient permissions or missing resources. Even though I am logged in as the repository owner.

I guess I need to learn what to put in externalEndpoints

[Update]

I tried this instead

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs: 
    command: 'pack'
    outputDir: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/TestDir'
```

Now the error becomes

```
 error MSB4057: The target "pack" does not exist in the project.
```

investigating [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41021034/error-msb4057-missing-target-pack-when-building-netstandard-nuget-package)

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/26543

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements-discussions/issues/9#issuecomment-322922859

Comment: I am going to try adding system.data.sqlclient to my standard library

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19172

Comment: I was experiencing this issue. I wonder if it is related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43995432/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-abstrac

Comment: When you developed the library project locally in VS, did the project references the three packages above? And if we create the nuget locally in VS(right-click project=>pack), and consume it in your another project, does it work all well? The error messages are a bit strange but since it works well when you `and then my project runs successfully`, it seems to me there should be something wrong with your `pack step` in Azure devops... Do you use dotnet pack command?

Comment: I updated the top of the question to show the references I am using and added the yaml near the end of the question. @LanceLi-MSFT  Investigating the pack idea.

Comment: Hmm, you use nuget pack. And as I know, there's one open issue for `nuget pack` command in .net core/.net standard projects. See [here](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4491), I think you should use `dotnet pack`(.net core task in Azure Devops and choose pack option) to create nuget correct package. Then consume it in your another project, rebuild and make sure all referenced assemblies are in output folder. Then it would work well...

Comment: If I create the Nuget pack locally it works. I will investigate your further suggestions

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT I updated the end of the question with my attempt to use dotnet pack  it did not work.

Comment: Not nuget related task, use [dotnet related task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops). See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops#pack). And it's recommended task if you're doing something with .net core/.net standard projects. See **Notes** in [Nuget Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget?view=azure-devops).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Although it would be ideal if the extra packages were added
>   automatically.

Assuming we have one `.net standard` project which depends on `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`, `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` and other packages. The expected behavior for us is to create a nuget package in whose `xx.nuspec` file has definitions about the [dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#dependencies-element).

But there's [one issue](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4491) about `nuget pack` command, it can't work well for .net core/standard project. Both `nuget pack` and `dotnet pack` can create `.net standard` nuget packages successfully, but `pack successfully` doesn't mean good package.

With the effect of the issue above, package created by `nuget pack` will lose some dependencies in `Package.nuspec` file.
(Rename xx.nupkg to xx.zip, then we can check the content inside package, we'll see the [xx.nuspec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec) file)

And above step can cause runtime error like `missing assembly`. So to make it ideal that the extra packages are added automatically and avoid missing reference, we recommend `dotnet pack` command for projects using PackageReference format. (No matter dotnet pack command locally or dotnet pack task in Azure Devops Piepilne)

Comment: I have run into problems trying to get the whole repository published. I think because it contains framework and standard projects.  I will ask a new question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60181799/can-i-mix-framework-projects-and-net-standard-projects-in-the-same-repository

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60197552/how-do-i-get-azure-devops-to-create-a-correct-nuspec-for-a-net-standard-2-0-pro

Answer (score 2):

I resolved the error by updating my test project with the package reference.

Specifically, I edited my project file to include the line below:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    ...
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" Version="5.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

just hit the same error with ASP.NET 4.7.2 (updated from net 4.6) project which reference netstandard 2.0 project (ef core 3.x). (on azure app service)

after trying to clean/rebuild/nuget reinstall .. i removed everything from app service and published project again. error dismissed.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the error, this issue occur due to a version difference between the version expected by the application and the version you have installed.

To resolve the version issue,
in Visual Studio, right click on the solution and go to Manage NuGet Packages for Solution option and then go to the Updates tab, search and select the reference that you have the issue with. Then upgrade/downgrade it to the version given in the error. (You might have to disable the package source temporarily from the NuGet option to do this.) To check whether you have installed the correct version of the reference, right click on the reference and go to Properties and check the version.

If the version is still not updated you may have to add it manually. To do this, in the solution explorer, right click on the references and go to Add reference option. Then select Browse. You will be directed to the file explorer. From there go to the project -> src -> packages -> reference name -> lib -> .net version and select the dll file for the reference. Then the reference will be correctly added.