# Can I mix framework projects and .net standard projects in the same repository? Dotnet Pack command

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In the [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60178092/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-data-sqlclient) I needed to change the build yaml from using Nuget to using DotNet
So that the .net standard project would pack correctly ( i hope ).  However when I did this I started getting

> error MSB4057: The target "pack" does not exist in the project

for the framework projects.

Should I be separating the repositories or is there some way to specify different pack commands for different targets?

My original azure-pipelines.yml was

```
# .NET Desktop
# Build and run tests for .NET Desktop or Windows classic desktop solutions.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/windows/dot-net

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  Major: '2'
  Minor: '0'
  Patch: '0'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '>=4.3.0'
    checkLatest: true

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: pack
    packagesToPack: '**/*.csproj'
    versioningScheme: byPrereleaseNumber
    majorVersion: '$(Major)'
    minorVersion: '$(Minor)'
    patchVersion: '$(Patch)'

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: pack
    packagesToPack: '**/*.vbproj'
    versioningScheme: byPrereleaseNumber
    majorVersion: '$(Major)'
    minorVersion: '$(Minor)'
    patchVersion: '$(Patch)'

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet push'
  inputs:
    command: push
    publishVstsFeed: 'SBDCommonFeed'
    allowPackageConflicts: true
```

but I changed the NuGetCommand@2 task to be

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs: 
    command: 'pack'
    outputDir: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/TestDir'
```

For the Nuget command I can experiment with PackagesToPack
What do I change for the DotNet command?

[Update]
I tried

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'pack'
    projects: '**/*Standard.csproj'
    outputDir: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/OutputDir'
```

Where *Standard are the .net standard projects. However there was still the MSB4057 error on a framework project

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops

Comment: You can also use `packagesToPack:` instead of `Projects:` to do dotnet pack. Since we only need to pack the .net standard project, you can pass something like :     `packagesToPack: '**/LibraryProjectName.csproj'`

Comment: Thats it. Thank you.

Comment: Feel free to let me know if the new created package can be consumed well in your project. (And you may need to [clean the nuget cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) to avoid old cache affects the nuget behavior.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates you're trying to pack both the `.net standard` project and `.net framework` project while you only need to pack the .net standard library project. (Also, dotnet pack should not be used to pack one non-library project.)

So the workaround is to specify the project to pack when using dotnet pack task. The `Pack` command in [.net core task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops) also supports `packagesToPack` element.

See `#packagesToPack: '**/*.csproj' # Required when command == Pack`.

Normally the format is:

```
steps:

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2  
  displayName: 'dotnet pack'
  inputs:
    command: pack
    packagesToPack: '**/ProjectName.csproj'
    configuration: Release
    versioningScheme: xxx
    minorVersion: xxx
    buildProperties: xxx
    ...
```